# Is it bad practice to create a second tkinter Tk() after the first instance has been destroyed by closing the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning about Tkinter and was wondering if it would cause errors if I did the following:

```
import tkinter as tk #import modules
from tkinter import ttk

parent=tk.Tk()  #create first instance
card1="k spades"
card2="k diamonds"
comboform=ttk.Combobox(parent,textvariable='form',values=[card1,card2,"both","neither"])#create combobox input form
comboform.grid(row=0,column=0)#added to grid
parent.geometry("200x200")
parent.mainloop()#displays tkinter window

#window exited

parent=tk.Tk()#new instance created

label=tk.Label(parent,text="hi")#label produced
label.pack()#added to window
parent.mainloop()
```

If I click the exit cross is that the same as parent.destroy(); is that good practice? I know you're only supposed to run mainloop() once and have one Tk() instance but if it's destroyed is it going to cause problems? It's not like I'm creating a class the produces a Tk() instance, where there's a risk of multiple instances existing at once.
I am hoping to, eventually,  have an application running in the IDLE and then have a tkinter window appear, presenting an input widget of some kind. After the user gives their input, the window would close and the user would continue in the main window. But could I then do it again, opening new windows (like the above code) on the provision that the instance of Tk() is destroyed each time?

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to be asking a slightly different question. If you need multiple windows, why are you creating multiple instances of `Tk` rather than one instance of `Tk` and then using `Toplevel` for the additional windows?

Comment: When you create new widgets/variables, you have to always pass in the `master` parameter (the first argument). As long as you do that you should be fine. That is what I do and I am yet to encounter a problem. People usually forget to pass in master when creating tkinter variables like this: `tk.StringVar(master=...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've destroyed the root window and then create a new one, that's perfectly fine.

The problem with creating multiple instances of Tk is that most people don't understand what that actually does. Having multiple instances of Tk is fine as long as you realize that they operate in completely memory spaces and widgets and bindings in one can't interact with widgets and bindings in the other.

All of that being said, the best practice is to create a single root window at the start of the program, and it stays alive until the program exits.  If you need additional windows, the best practice is to create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thanks! So, ideally, you wouldn't do the above code and would use Toplevel windows? Also, does parent.destroy() do the same thing as clicking the exit button?

Comment: @ThomasStokes: Clicking the exit button does the same thing as calling destroy on that window. And yes, `Toplevels` are designed to be the preferred solution if you need more than one window.